# Office 365 shortcuts conflict with chrome shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard, ms-office, google-chrome

The following reference for [Outlook 2016 on macOS](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/complete-list-keyboard-shortcuts-outlook-2016-mac/)  lists *CMD-N* as "new message". However that is already "owned" by *chrome* and in fact launches a new Chrome window. Is that list of shortcuts incorrect? Or is there something else I must do to use those shortcuts?

Comment: You should make it clear whether a) you are running Outlook within Chrome for which the list of shortcuts can't apply, or b) running both the Outlook and Chrome Mac apps.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd> is a universal Mac keyboard shortcut only that means, "create something new in this app."

In MS Word it is a new MS Word document. In mail.app it is a new mail message. In Chrome/Firefox/Safari it is a new browser window, and so on.

There are other such keyboard shortcuts on the Mac that are similar in different apps and some that are identical. <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd> springs to mind as the way to print the current view in whatever app you are using.

Note that macOS is *DIFFERNT* than Linux and Windows as closing a Window does not (necessarily) quit out of the app itself. When you see Google Chrome but get a new Outlook message look at the top of your screen. Just to the right of the Apple menu, is the name of the **currently active** app.

The important thing to do is click on the window, look up to verify you are in the expected app and then do your keyboard shortcut.

If you come from Windows or Linux it is weird, confusing and *"just plain wrong!"* But that is the way the Mac works and has always worked.

Comment: @WestCoastProjects That is unfair.  The question read very likely as newbie question and was answered accordingly.  Seemed like you didn't realise that the Mac app you were running was Chrome and not the Outlook Mac App as you referenced in your link.